# Avoid multiple insert into oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, plsql, sql-insert

**Faster way to load 100,000 rows. Instead of multiple inserts want 1 insert ** I have a script that takes data from multiple oracle tables. Based on the order types, there are multiple inserts to a temp table. 100,000 or more records to be inserted based on order type. Multiple inserts based on order type is taking 12-14 minutes. Any faster way?

```
               prompt Querying freight ...
            SET serveroutput ON SIZE 1000000
            DECLARE

               CURSOR c_progpcon 
               IS
                  SELECT cust_id
                        ,div_no
                    FROM dss.program_processing_controls;

               CURSOR c_custord(in_orgrole_id_customer IN dss.orders.orgrole_id_customer%TYPE)
               IS
                  SELECT id order_id
                        ,order_type
                        ,order_number
                        ,customer_po
                    FROM dss.orders
                    WHERE order_type = 'CUST'
                      AND orgrole_id_customer = in_orgrole_id_customer;

               CURSOR c_outbound(in_order_id IN dss.orders.id%TYPE)
               IS
                  SELECT ship.id ship_id
                        ,ship.shipper_no
                        ,shptrk.id shptrk_id
                        ,shptrk.waybill
                        ,shptrk.estimated_freight
                        ,shptrk.actual_freight
                        ,shptrk.dt_created
                    FROM dss.shipments ship
                        ,dss.shipment_trackings shptrk
                    WHERE ship.order_id = in_order_id
                      AND shptrk.ship_id = ship.id
                     -- and ship.id = 2290451
                      AND shptrk.dt_created BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-JAN-2017','dd-MON-yyyy') 
                                                   AND TO_DATE('31-DEC-2017','dd-MON-yyyy');

               CURSOR c_ordsch(in_order_id IN dss.orders.id%TYPE)
               IS
                  SELECT ordsch.id ordsch_id
                    FROM dss.orders ord
                        ,dss.ordered_items orditm
                        ,dss.ordered_item_schedules ordsch
                    WHERE ord.id = in_order_id
                      AND orditm.order_id = ord.id
                      AND ordsch.orditm_id = orditm.id;

               CURSOR c_inbound(in_orditm_id IN dss.ordered_items.id%TYPE)
               IS
                  SELECT recshp.id recshp_id
                        ,recshp.waybill
                        ,recshp.estimated_freight
                        ,recshp.actual_freight
                        ,recshp.dt_created
                    FROM dss.built_items bltitm
                        ,dss.received_shipments recshp
                    WHERE bltitm.orditm_id_rcvd = in_orditm_id
                      AND recshp.id = bltitm.recshp_id
                      AND recshp.dt_created BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-JAN-2017','dd-MON-yyyy') 
                                                    AND TO_DATE('31-DEC-2017','dd-MON-yyyy')
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT recshp.id recshp_id
                        ,recshp.waybill
                        ,recshp.estimated_freight
                        ,recshp.actual_freight
                        ,recshp.dt_created
                    FROM dss.received_items rcvitm
                        ,dss.received_shipments recshp
                    WHERE rcvitm.orditm_id_rcvd = in_orditm_id
                      AND recshp.id = rcvitm.recshp_id
                      AND recshp.dt_created BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-JAN-2017','dd-MON-yyyy') 
                                                    AND TO_DATE('31-DEC-2017','dd-MON-yyyy');

               v_cust_processed NUMBER := 0;
               v_custord_processed NUMBER := 0;
               v_orgrole_id_customer dss.org_roles.id%TYPE;

               v_estimated_freight_custord adwaram.order_freight.estimated_freight%TYPE;
               v_actual_freight_custord adwaram.order_freight.actual_freight%TYPE;

               v_orditm_id_core dss.exchange_cores.orditm_id%TYPE;
               v_order_id_core dss.orders.id%TYPE;
               v_bltitm_id_core dss.po_histories.bltitm_id%TYPE;

               v_order_type dss.orders.order_type%TYPE;
               v_order_number dss.orders.order_number%TYPE;

               v_order_id_xfer dss.orders.id%TYPE;
               v_order_id_inbound dss.orders.id%TYPE;
               v_orditm_id_po ordered_items.id%TYPE;

               --anu
               v_calc_freight number:=0;
               v_method varchar2(4000);

            BEGIN

               FOR c_progpcon_rec IN c_progpcon
               LOOP

                  v_cust_processed := v_cust_processed + 1;
                  SELECT orgrole_id
                    INTO v_orgrole_id_customer
                    FROM dss.customers
                   WHERE id = c_progpcon_rec.cust_id;

                  FOR c_custord_rec IN c_custord(v_orgrole_id_customer)
                  LOOP

                     v_custord_processed := v_custord_processed + 1;

                     -- outbound customer order
                     FOR c_outbound_rec IN c_outbound(c_custord_rec.order_id)
                     LOOP
                        begin
                          v_calc_freight:=DSS.PKG_ESTIMATED_FREIGHT.GET_ESTIMATED_FREIGHT
                                         (null,c_outbound_rec.ship_id,v_method);
                           exception
                            when others then
                            v_calc_freight := 0;

                        end;
                        INSERT INTO adwaram.order_freight
                           (order_type
                           ,order_number
                           ,shipper_no
                           ,waybill
                           ,actual_freight
                           ,estimated_freight
                           ,waybill_entered
                           ,order_id
                           ,ship_id
                           ,shptrk_id
                           ,recshp_id
                           ,cust_id
                           ,order_id_cust
                           ,notes
                           ,dt_created)
                           VALUES
                           (c_custord_rec.order_type
                           ,c_custord_rec.order_number
                           ,c_outbound_rec.shipper_no
                           ,c_outbound_rec.waybill
                           ,c_outbound_rec.actual_freight
                           ,v_calc_freight--c_outbound_rec.estimated_freight
                           ,c_outbound_rec.dt_created
                           ,c_custord_rec.order_id
                           ,c_outbound_rec.ship_id
                           ,c_outbound_rec.shptrk_id
                           ,NULL
                           ,c_progpcon_rec.cust_id
                           ,c_custord_rec.order_id
                           ,'OUTBOUND CUST ORDER'
                           ,SYSDATE);

                     END LOOP;

                     FOR c_ordsch_rec IN c_ordsch(c_custord_rec.order_id)
                     LOOP

                        -- get core
                        BEGIN

                           SELECT xccore.orditm_id
                                 ,pohist.bltitm_id
                             INTO v_orditm_id_po
                                 ,v_bltitm_id_core
                             FROM dss.exchange_units xcunit
                                 ,dss.exchange_cores xccore
                                 ,dss.po_histories pohist
                            WHERE xcunit.ordsch_id = c_ordsch_rec.ordsch_id
                              AND xccore.xcitm_id = xcunit.xcitm_id
                              AND pohist.orditm_id(+) = xccore.orditm_id;

                           IF v_bltitm_id_core IS NOT NULL
                           THEN
                              v_order_id_core := dss.pkg_inven.func_get_order(v_bltitm_id_core
                                                                             ,'ORDER_ID');
                              v_orditm_id_core := dss.pkg_inven.func_get_order(v_bltitm_id_core
                                                                              ,'ORDITM_ID');
                           ELSE
                              v_order_id_core := NULL;
                           END IF;

                           IF v_order_id_core IS NOT NULL
                           THEN

                              -- outbound order for received core (repair order or customer order)
                              FOR c_outbound_rec IN c_outbound(v_order_id_core)
                              LOOP
                                     begin
                                        v_calc_freight:=DSS.PKG_ESTIMATED_FREIGHT.GET_ESTIMATED_FREIGHT
                                         (null,c_outbound_rec.ship_id,v_method);
                                      exception
                                       when others then
                                      v_calc_freight := 0;

                                     end;
                                 SELECT order_type
                                       ,order_number
                                   INTO v_order_type
                                       ,v_order_number
                                   FROM dss.orders
                                  WHERE id = v_order_id_core;

                                 INSERT INTO adwaram.order_freight
                                    (order_type
                                    ,order_number
                                    ,shipper_no
                                    ,waybill
                                    ,actual_freight
                                    ,estimated_freight
                                    ,waybill_entered
                                    ,order_id
                                    ,ship_id
                                    ,shptrk_id
                                    ,recshp_id
                                    ,cust_id
                                    ,order_id_cust
                                    ,notes
                                    ,dt_created)
                                    VALUES
                                    (v_order_type
                                    ,v_order_number
                                    ,c_outbound_rec.shipper_no
                                    ,c_outbound_rec.waybill
                                    ,c_outbound_rec.actual_freight
                                    ,v_calc_freight--c_outbound_rec.estimated_freight
                                    ,c_outbound_rec.dt_created
                                    ,v_order_id_core
                                    ,c_outbound_rec.ship_id
                                    ,c_outbound_rec.shptrk_id
                                    ,NULL
                                    ,c_progpcon_rec.cust_id
                                    ,c_custord_rec.order_id
                                    ,'OUTBOUND '||v_order_type||' ORDER'
                                    ,SYSDATE);

                              END LOOP;

                           END IF;

                           -- xfer related to customer order
                           BEGIN

                              SELECT ord.id
                                INTO v_order_id_xfer
                                FROM dss.orders ord
                                    ,dss.ordered_items orditm
                               WHERE ord.order_type = 'XFER'
                                 AND ord.div_no = c_progpcon_rec.div_no
                                 AND orditm.order_id = ord.id
                                 AND orditm.customer_po = c_custord_rec.customer_po;

                              FOR c_outbound_rec IN c_outbound(v_order_id_xfer)
                              LOOP
                                 begin
                                   v_calc_freight:=DSS.PKG_ESTIMATED_FREIGHT.GET_ESTIMATED_FREIGHT
                                             ( null,c_outbound_rec.ship_id,v_method);

                                     exception
                                      when others then
                                        v_calc_freight := 0;

                                 end;

                                 SELECT order_type
                                       ,order_number
                                   INTO v_order_type
                                       ,v_order_number
                                   FROM dss.orders
                                  WHERE id = v_order_id_xfer;

                                 INSERT INTO adwaram.order_freight
                                    (order_type
                                    ,order_number
                                    ,shipper_no
                                    ,waybill
                                    ,actual_freight
                                    ,estimated_freight
                                    ,waybill_entered
                                    ,order_id
                                    ,ship_id
                                    ,shptrk_id
                                    ,recshp_id
                                    ,cust_id
                                    ,order_id_cust
                                    ,notes
                                    ,dt_created)
                                    VALUES
                                    (v_order_type
                                    ,v_order_number
                                    ,c_outbound_rec.shipper_no
                                    ,c_outbound_rec.waybill
                                    ,c_outbound_rec.actual_freight
                                    ,v_calc_freight--c_outbound_rec.estimated_freight
                                    ,c_outbound_rec.dt_created
                                    ,v_order_id_xfer
                                    ,c_outbound_rec.ship_id
                                    ,c_outbound_rec.shptrk_id
                                    ,NULL
                                    ,c_progpcon_rec.cust_id
                                    ,c_custord_rec.order_id
                                    ,'OUTBOUND '||v_order_type||' ORDER'
                                    ,SYSDATE);

                              END LOOP;

                           EXCEPTION
                              WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
                                   OR TOO_MANY_ROWS
                              THEN
                                 NULL;
                           END;


                           -- inbound orders associate with exchange - v_orditm_id_core (if ro)
                           --                                          v_orditm_id_po (csp po)
                           IF v_orditm_id_core IS NOT NULL
                           THEN

                              FOR c_inbound_rec IN c_inbound(v_orditm_id_core)
                              LOOP
                                    begin
                                       v_calc_freight:=DSS.PKG_ESTIMATED_FREIGHT.GET_ESTIMATED_FREIGHT
                                             ( c_inbound_rec.recshp_id,null,v_method);

                                        exception
                                          when others then
                                            v_calc_freight := 0;

                                    end;
                                 SELECT ord.order_type
                                       ,ord.order_number
                                       ,ord.id
                                   INTO v_order_type
                                       ,v_order_number
                                       ,v_order_id_inbound
                                   FROM dss.ordered_items orditm
                                       ,dss.orders ord
                                  WHERE orditm.id = v_orditm_id_core
                                    AND ord.id = orditm.order_id;

                                 INSERT INTO adwaram.order_freight
                                    (order_type
                                    ,order_number
                                    ,shipper_no
                                    ,waybill
                                    ,actual_freight
                                    ,estimated_freight
                                    ,waybill_entered
                                    ,order_id
                                    ,ship_id
                                    ,shptrk_id
                                    ,recshp_id
                                    ,cust_id
                                    ,order_id_cust
                                    ,notes
                                    ,dt_created)
                                    VALUES
                                    (v_order_type
                                    ,v_order_number
                                    ,NULL
                                    ,c_inbound_rec.waybill
                                    ,c_inbound_rec.actual_freight
                                    ,v_calc_freight--c_inbound_rec.estimated_freight
                                    ,c_inbound_rec.dt_created
                                    ,v_order_id_inbound
                                    ,NULL
                                    ,NULL
                                    ,c_inbound_rec.recshp_id
                                    ,c_progpcon_rec.cust_id
                                    ,c_custord_rec.order_id
                                    ,'INBOUND '||v_order_type||' ORDER'
                                    ,SYSDATE);

                              END LOOP;

                           END IF;

                           IF v_orditm_id_po IS NOT NULL
                           THEN

                              FOR c_inbound_rec IN c_inbound(v_orditm_id_po)
                              LOOP
                              begin
                              v_calc_freight:=DSS.PKG_ESTIMATED_FREIGHT.GET_ESTIMATED_FREIGHT
                                         ( c_inbound_rec.recshp_id
                                         ,NULL
                                         , v_method
                                         );
               exception
                         when others then
                         v_calc_freight := 0;

                        end;

                                 SELECT ord.order_type
                                       ,ord.order_number
                                       ,ord.id
                                   INTO v_order_type
                                       ,v_order_number
                                       ,v_order_id_inbound
                                   FROM dss.ordered_items orditm
                                       ,dss.orders ord
                                  WHERE orditm.id = v_orditm_id_po
                                    AND ord.id = orditm.order_id;

                                 INSERT INTO adwaram.order_freight
                                    (order_type
                                    ,order_number
                                    ,shipper_no
                                    ,waybill
                                    ,actual_freight
                                    ,estimated_freight
                                    ,waybill_entered
                                    ,order_id
                                    ,ship_id
                                    ,shptrk_id
                                    ,recshp_id
                                    ,cust_id
                                    ,order_id_cust
                                    ,notes
                                    ,dt_created)
                                    VALUES
                                    (v_order_type
                                    ,v_order_number
                                    ,NULL
                                    ,c_inbound_rec.waybill
                                    ,c_inbound_rec.actual_freight
                                    ,v_calc_freight--c_inbound_rec.estimated_freight
                                    ,c_inbound_rec.dt_created
                                    ,v_order_id_inbound
                                    ,NULL
                                    ,NULL
                                    ,c_inbound_rec.recshp_id
                                    ,c_progpcon_rec.cust_id
                                    ,c_custord_rec.order_id
                                    ,'INBOUND '||v_order_type||' ORDER'
                                    ,SYSDATE);

                              END LOOP;

                           END IF;

                        EXCEPTION
                           WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
                                OR TOO_MANY_ROWS 
                           THEN
                              NULL;
                        END;

                     END LOOP;

                  END LOOP;

               END LOOP;

               COMMIT;
               dbms_output.put_line(TO_CHAR(v_cust_processed)||' customers processed.');
               dbms_output.put_line(TO_CHAR(v_custord_processed)||' customer orders processed.');

            END;
            /
```

Comment: Yes, there are much faster ways...cursors are slow, find another method.  Unfortunately don't have the time to go through that massive script though

Comment: Can you give me any example?

Comment: You asked this question a couple of days back (but it looks like you deleted it). Obviously you didn't get a satisfactory answer then and you won't get one now. This is an unanswerable question. You cannot reasonably expect strangers to scroll through several hundred lines of poorly formatted, shonky code without any explanation of business rules. We aren't here to do your job for you.

Comment: In your code you always process the data line by line which is basically the slowest way of doing it. Transform your insert to `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM ...`. If this is not possible (though from a quick view to your code it should be no problem) consider `BULK COLLECT INTO` and `FORALL` operation. Skip `v_cust_processed` and `v_custord_processed` processing/output, you don't need them.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check the execution plans for all Queries, make sure that they work
   as expected
2. Bulk Processing with BULK COLLECT and FORALL as described in
   this [Oracle Magazine Article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-sep/o52plsql-1709862.html) By Steven Feuerstein may help.

Comment: tried using bulk collect. 
getting error,  
FOR i1 IN 1 .. c_outbound_tab.count LOOP

begin 
-- bulk insert

FORALL i1 IN 1 .. c_outbound_tab.count 

PLS-00436: implementation restriction: cannot reference fields of BULK In-BIND table of records

Comment: could not post all the code.

Comment: -- fill pl/sql table
         OPEN c_outbound(c_custord_rec.order_id);
         FETCH c_outbound BULK COLLECT INTO c_outbound_tab;
         CLOSE c_outbound;